# Android анимация вращения

Tags: android, xml, анимация, android-animation

Есть RelativeLayout с несколькими view внутри. 
Как сделать анимацию вращения вокруг оси Y как на рисунке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте класс ObjectAnimator. Очень прост в использовании

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourView, "rotationY", 0.0f, 360f);
animation.setDuration(2400);
animation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
animation.start();
```

Comment: Код почему-то не работает, но спасибо за наводку.

Comment: @Алексей все работает, замените второй параметр `rotationByY` на `View.ROTATION_Y`

Comment: Нет, просто не ту вьюху передавал)) Работает, спасибо!)

Comment: @Алексей вот давайте не будим вводить людей в заблуждение, вариант с `rotationByY` не работает, необходимо либо писать `View.ROTATION_Y` либо `rotationY` что в принципе равнозначно